# Este adaptador se conecta con RecyclerView y evento onClick de item no funciona correctamente

Tags: java, android, adapter

Esta es mi AvistAdapter.java donde la conecto con mi List reporteEspecie

```
public class AvistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AvistAdapter.ViewHolder>{


private int LEFT_CELL = 1;
private int RIGHT_CELL = 0;
private List<ReporteEspecie> reporteEspecie;
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void OnItemClick (int position);
}
public void setOnItemClickListener (OnItemClickListener listener){
    mListener = listener;

}

public AvistAdapter(List<ReporteEspecie> reporteEspecie){
    super();
    this.reporteEspecie = reporteEspecie;

}
//
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position % 2 == 0){

        return RIGHT_CELL;

    }
    else {

        return LEFT_CELL;

    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    if(LEFT_CELL == viewType) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout_right,parent,false);
    } else {

        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout_left,parent,false);
    }

    return new ViewHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.TxtTitulo.setText(reporteEspecie.get(position).getEspecie());
    holder.TxtDetalle.setText(reporteEspecie.get(position).getDireccion());
    holder.TxtDetalle2.setText(reporteEspecie.get(position).getFechaYhora().toString());
    //holder.ImgPhoto.setImageResource(reporteEspecie.get(position).getImage());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return reporteEspecie.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;

    public TextView TxtTitulo;
    public TextView TxtDetalle;
    public TextView TxtDetalle2;
    //public ImageView ImgPhoto;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

        TxtTitulo = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitulo);
        TxtDetalle = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txtDetalle);
        TxtDetalle2 = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txtDetalle2);
        //ImgPhoto = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imgPhoto);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("Mensaje",reporteEspecie.get(getAdapterPosition()).getDoc());



            }
        });


    }

  }


}
```

El log.d me funciona correctamente indicandome el campo Doc de cada Item al dar click y en el orden correcto, lo que necesito es pasar de esta EspeciesActivity.java que es donde me muestra la lista hacia CompleteActivity.java donde necesito llevar ese campo Doc a la cual le di click

EspeciesActivity.java

```
public class EspeciesActivity extends RegistrosActivity {

private static final String TAG = "FireLog";
private RecyclerView mMainList;
private FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
public AvistAdapter avistAdapter;
public List<ReporteEspecie> reporteEspecies;

FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
TextView DocUd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_especies);

    DocUd = findViewById(R.id.tvDocUd);

    Locale locale = new Locale("es_ES");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    this.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

    reporteEspecies = new ArrayList<>();
    avistAdapter = new AvistAdapter(reporteEspecies);

    mMainList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_list);

    mMainList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mMainList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mMainList.setAdapter(avistAdapter);

    mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    mFirestore.collection("Data")
            .document(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName())
            .collection("Reportes")
            .orderBy("id")
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots,FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if(e !=null){

                        Log.d(TAG, "Error: "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                    for (final DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){

                        if(doc.getType()== DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){

                            final ReporteEspecie reporteEspecie = doc.getDocument().toObject(ReporteEspecie.class);

                            reporteEspecies.add(reporteEspecie);

                            avistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    }

                }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear el intent dentro del onclick y enviarlo a CompleteActivity enviando el Doc que supongo es un String.

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("Mensaje",reporteEspecie.get(getAdapterPosition()).getDoc());
                Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), CompleteActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("doc", reporteEspecie.get(getAdapterPosition()).getDoc());
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

De está manera envias el dato a CompleteActivity y en esa clase la recibes como un extra normal.

```
String doc = getIntent().getStringExtra("doc");
```

En el caso de que sea un objeto deberas implementar en tu objeto la interfaz Serializable o Parcelable, Saludos!

Comment: Gracias Amigo Por Ahora Funcionando Solo me faltaba usar la vista corrrecta lo puse asi Intent intent = new Intent(mView.getContext(), CompleteActivity.class);

Comment: Cierto, es que llevo rato sin usar java y se me olvida. voy a corregir